# Query 2 mysql tables using same div #id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just a general question. I have code that queries db and returns the results into a dropdown. What I need to do is query 2 different tables using the same div #id. For example, in the code I have attached, you will see that it use's the same selector. is it possible to query 2 tables and return the results to 2 different div #id's as in my example. Many thanks.

```
$(function() {
  $("#dstr_dept").change(function() {
    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><imgages src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
    $.get('loadboxAdrDstrsubcat.php?dstraddr=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
      $("#dstr_address").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#dstr_address").trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
    });
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#dstr_dept").change(function() {
    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><imgages src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
    $.get('loadboxDstrsubcat.php?dstrdept=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
      $("#box_dstr").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#box_dstr").trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this -

```
$(function() {
  $("#dstr_dept").change(function() {
    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading files" /></div>');
    $.get('loadboxAdrDstrsubcat.php?dstraddr=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
      $("#dstr_address, #box_dstr").html(data);
      $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#dstr_address, #box_dstr").trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Note how the selectors are combined. I do not see requests to two different queries though you could run multiple `$.get()` statements under the one change event.

Comment: Thanks for that Jay. Could you give example of running multiple $.get() to query 2 tables. Thanks

Comment: You would add another `$.get` pointed to a different PHP file or the same PHP file with a different query string.